# How do I set UIButton shadow color in Xcode 13 inspector?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard, xcode13, inspector

How do I set UIButton shadow color in Xcode 13 storyboard ui element inspector?
I see only control for the text itself and for shadow offset. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the button's style from "*Plain*" to "*Default*" and you will see a property where you can define the shadow color of the UIButton.

[image: Interface Builder options of Style "Default"]